# How to order Laravel model based on number of visits in related model?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

In Laravel, I have A `Story` model with an `episodes()` `HasMany` relationship to the `Episode` model and I also have a `Visit` model with a `visits()` `MorphMany` relationship to the `Episode` model, how do I order `Story` based upon the number of visits from its related `episodes()` so that stories with episodes with more visits would be given more priority.

`Story` model

```php
public function episodes()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Episode::class);
}
```

`Episode` model

```php
public function visits()
{
    return $this->morphMany(Visit::class, 'visitable');
}
```

I have tried using Laravel's `withCount()` method and other different approaches, but can't seem to get it right.

Here is one of them:

```php
$stories = Story::withCount(['episodes' => function ($query) {
                $query->withCount('visits');
            }])
            ->orderByDesc('episodes_visits_count')
            ->get();
```

How can I order the Story model based on the number of visits from its related episodes() using Laravel's withCount() method?

Comment: You probably need to use some `join()` calls to make the appropriate tables available to your `stories` query; I can't say I've ever tried to use `withCount()` nested like that.

Comment: Can you suggest with an answer?

Comment: Nope, I don't know the correct syntax for your tables, but look up how to do `join()`s on Laravel queries, connect your tables and then order by `visits.visit_count` (or whatever column).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try aliasing the relationship count as mentioned in the end of this [docs section](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) like:

```php
$stories = Story::withCount([
        'episodes', 
        'episodes as visits_count' => function ($query) {
            $query->withCount('visits');
        }])
    ->orderByDesc('visits_count')
    ->get();
```

Comment: This worked as charm, thanks so much. Made a minor change from ```'episodes', 'episodes as...``` to ```'episodes  as...```, but it totally worked.